# How to review previous onion comment or tip

Tags: anonymity

I submitted an anonymous tip and want to review it and see if there has been any answer. How do I do that?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Which website did you leave the tip on?

Comment: http://odazpl6u3vhoedhn.onion/lookup#codename-hint  cbc securedrop

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [login page](http://odazpl6u3vhoedhn.onion/):

Log in with your your codename.  If you have lost or forgotten your codename then it is not possible to review responses.

Comment: I'm able to login successfully but there is no link to previous tip/comment/files sent.

Comment: I just created a test message, logged out and then logged back in. At the bottom of the page is says:

"Read Replies
There are no replies at this time." If there were replies, they would probably be in that section.